# Isomorphism functorially

Tags: abstract-algebra, homotopy-theory

I was reading the lecture notes of Pierre Schapira

http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~schapira/lectnotes/AlTo.pdf
I am not able to understand  one thing. Please help. 
In page 75, theorem 4.6.1, the author says that 'quasi-isomorphism from X to $\lambda(X)$ is functorial in C. What does it mean.  What does isomorphism functorially mean in general?
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that given a morphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$, the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\lambda(X) @>{\lambda(f)}>> \lambda(Y)
\end{CD}
$$
is commutative, where the vertical arrows are the said quasi-isomorphisms.